# Memory leack caused by executing "su"

Tags: java, android

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

When running above command on **rooted** phone everything works fine

But when i try same code on **non-rooted** device its causing memory leak, i can see multiple instances of my app in task manager and they cant bee killed. The more times i run this code memory gets less and less until phone totally freezes and i have to restart

This is the exception i get

```
01-24 11:06:56.459: E/App (8307): Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

Why is this hapening and how can i prevent it?